# Angular user logged in and session lost - how to check and redirect?

Tags: angular, session, routes

What happens when a user is logged in but the session has gone stale?

In this situation I lose, for example, my users name from the session so name displays as "null".

So I need to redirect back to login right?

So in my app-routing.module.ts, I have  `{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }` at the end and everything works perfectly. Except for now - when my session is lost so I need to redirect to login. How do I configure that? I have AuthGuard on all the necessary pages.

Is my understanding correct? I intend to add JWT at a later stage if that's relevant.

Comment: you can acheive this by Angular route gaurds

Answer (score 0):

You can add route gaurd to  module which is accessable with access token. in route gaurd will add condition user session experied or it if experied   redirect  to home

```
{ path: 'route', component: Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    if (/*user is logged in*/) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/Login']);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```